# Changes in ifcfg-eth1 file does not affect, even after reboot

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I'm trying to add a static IP to eth1 interface in CentOS by modifying ifcfg-eth1 and changing it to

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
IiPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eth1
UUID=429bdd44-cd14-46f4-b846-87d76a0444ff
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR0=10.20.21.234
NETMASK0=255.255.255.252
GATEWAY0=10.20.21.233
DEVICE=eth1
NOZEROCONF=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
HWADDR=00:14:4D:01:64:0C
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
```

But even after a reboot it does not affect and the output of `ip addr show` for eth1 is as the following:

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state 
UP qlen 1000
link/ether 00:14:4d:01:64:2a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.116/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth1
   valid_lft 187sec preferred_lft 187sec
inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe01:642a/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Why doesn't it change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ifcfg-eth1 profile is for a different MAC address than your actual interface.

So NetworkManager does not use it, and generates a temporary profile instead.

- You can change the `HWADDR=` field to your new MAC address.
- You can use `nmcli con` to manage multiple profiles.